# How to upgrade from Apache 2.2.18 to 2.2.19 on win32?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

When I try to install v2.2.19 it complains that another version is already installed.

Is it correct to uninstall v2.2.18 and then install 2.2.19?  Will doing so mess with my configuration files that I set up using v2.2.18?  I wish to retain these going to v2.2.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I went ahead and tried to see what would happen after backing up my config file.

It works to uninstall the old version and then install the later version, the config file is preserved and not overwritten.  All appears as before the upgrade.